# Adjust the table width to be the column width

Tags: tables

I am trying to make the table wider, I already made an adjust box with text width but nothing happed .. anyone can help me please?

My code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Three different Noise Levels}
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        \textbf{V output}\textbf{} & &  \textbf{SNR Level} \\
        \hline
        From  & To    &  \\
        \hline
        -inf    & 0     & Low \\
        0     & 20    & Medium \\
        20    & inf    & High \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}%
        \end{adjustbox}
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to widen the table? There's no need for it. Rather, use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{V output}}` in order for it to span both columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `tabularx` spanning the whole `\columnwidth` instead of a `tabular`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent x\hrulefill x

\begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Three different Noise Levels}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{YcY}
        \hline
        \textbf{V output}\textbf{} & &  \textbf{SNR Level} \\
        \hline
        From  & To    &  \\
        \hline
        -inf    & 0     & Low \\
        0     & 20    & Medium \\
        20    & inf    & High \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works perfect but the alignment of the columns is not in the middle ..could u plz help me to do so? Thanks a lot

Comment: @SMH Probably you want `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{YYY}`?